# ProcessStartInfo doesn't start application and Error code -532462766

Tags: c#, process, exit-code

I'm trying to launch an application from another using System.Diagnostic.Process that way :

```
if (this.isRequiredFieldFilled())
{
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();                

    MessageBox.Show("PIC" + up.pathPIC);
    start.FileName = up.pathPIC;

    //start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    //start.CreateNoWindow = true;
    int exitCode;

    try
    {
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
            MessageBox.Show(exitCode.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception  -> " + ex.Message);
    }

}
else
{
    //TODO Handle input
}
```

I can see the spinner but nothing apear and i receive the return code ->  -532462766 
I don't really understand because, when I double click on this application there is no problem, and if I launch another app from my process it work well too.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  I specified notepad.exe as my filename, but it launched successfully, returned a 0 after I closed it.  I'd check that your path doesn't have spaces in it or something like that, especially since you indicated it works fine with other apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, then maybe the problem come from the other app ? but have you an idea of what could it be ? it seem strange !

Comment: The return code is provided by the application you're launching and there's no rule for how the developer implements it, so you'll need to see if it's described on documentation or the app have a support channel. Some things you can look at are parameters you need to send to the executable, the permissions the user you're imporsonating may be lacking and another environment stuff.

Comment: I'd say that you're probably correct, the other app is to blame.  Wish I did, but I have no idea what the other app is, what it's supposed to do, etc.   That code is coming from the app though.

Comment: Are you able to launch it manually?

Comment: Yes ,and i wrote it too.

Comment: -532462766 == 0xE0434352, that's the exception code for a .NET program that died on an unhandled exception.  Well, that's not a well-written program, using the AppDomain.UnhandledException event to display *some* diagnostic is an oversight.  It probably has some more bugs.  Traditional ways to crash a program with Process.Start() is by not specifying the full path of the file you pass and not setting the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hans , i solved it by setting the WorkingDirectory property. I don't understand the AppDomain.UnhandledException part of your message, have you more information ?

Answer (score 0):

I received similar error when I was trying to run a windows application from an SSIS package. When I went to the Windows System Event viewer, I was able to see the exact error that was causing the issue. There was an access error and the service account running the application didn't have access to a particular resource. When I resolved the access issue, the process started running successfully.